# Here url Not working but modal open properly

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

If ajax call ok than a href not working or if i stop ajax call than href ok, But i want both work on click

```
<a href="'.$row['ad_url'].'"  target="_blank"  onclick="myfunction();"  id="'.$row['id'].'"  class="btn btn-mg btnad"  data-toggle="myfunction();" data-target="#showadDetailsModal">View</a>
```

Ajax Request

```
    $("body").on("click", ".btnad", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        
        details_id = $(this).attr('id');
        
        $.ajax({
           url: 'assets/php/process.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { details_id: details_id },
            success:function(response){
               data = JSON.parse(response);
                $("#getID").text(data.id);
                $("#getTitle").text(data.ad_title);                                  
                $("#getUser_coin").text(data.user_coin);
                                     
              
            }
        });
        
    });
```

Comment: what url is not working? the `href` of the link or the url of your ajax call? if the second, then maybe the browser console can give you further hints

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to initiate an AJAX request *and* follow the link. You can't reliably do both an an asynchronous thing (ie an AJAX request) and still allow the browser to follow a link to a new page.

Instead, you should drop your use of AJAX, and instead allow your browser to perform a normal request to `assets/php/process.php`, but hae that page redirect the browser to the page you want to show next.